# Writing an LC3 Subtraction subroutine to subtract R3 from R2

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm just starting to learn LC3. If we want to write a Subtraction subroutine which subtracts the value stored in some register, lets say we want to subtract the value stored in  `R3` from `R2` meaning that `R2 - R3` and store the value back into `R3`. How is this done using LC3 subroutines?

```
SUBT    NOT R3, R3 ; Find the complement of R3
        ADD R4, R3, #1 ; Getting 2's complement, R4 = -R3
        ADD R3, R2, R4 ; R3 -> R2 + R4 = R2 - R3
        RET
```

So far I have this.

expected output:

```
009-001=008 
004-004=000 
008-002=006 
003-002=001 
001-000=001 
005-001=004 
009-003=006 
008-004=004 
000-000=000 
002-001=001
```

Output received:

```
009-001=001
004-004=004
008-002=002
003-002=002
001-000=000
005-001=001
009-003=003
008-004=004
000-000=000
002-001=001
```

Call made:

```
BRz     C_MINUS
ADD     R0, R4, #-2
C_MINUS JSR     SUBT            ; '-'
BRnzp   C_end
```

Comment: Whatever you're doing that is wrong is not in the code you're showing.  Your subtraction is ok.  You should be able to see this by single stepping in the debugger and viewing the input & output values to the function.  (FYI, you don't need to use R4 as a temporary, you can keep using R3.)

Comment: `C_MINUS JSR  SUBT   ; '-'`  
           `BRnzp C_end`
`BRz  C_MINUS
  ADD  R0, R4, #-2`
This is the call made to the subroutine in the code

Comment: Ok, well, I don't see where values are being placed into registers for the call, e.g. R2 & R3, or how the caller uses the return value, so still not enough information to help find the issue, but I maintain that the subtraction code is ok.

Comment: Would it help to know the data file?

Comment: The output uniformly matches the second operand. Could it be that you are outputting the wrong variable?

Comment: This needs to be debugged.  Debugging is an interactive activity not well suited to a Q&A internet forum.  If you don't know how to debug, then now is a good time to learn.  Get to know single step and have perseverance.